# Use define, but the factory function cannot be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, amd

Currently use `define` to load a module, and define a callback function to set up the logic code, the callback function seems not to be executed.

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.myNamingSpace = {
        // ...
    };
});
```

Suppose my page has loaded the `jquery` module, so the callback function should be executed, but I still cannot get `$.myNamingSpace`.
Could someone help to explain about how the factory function works for `define`, and when the factory will be executed? Thanks!

Comment: where is defined your name space ? you have to add the some dependencies define(['jquery','yourplugin'], function($) {

Comment: don't get that. This is an anonymous module with only one dependency - jquery.